# Efficient way to find similar items in a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of list as follows:

```
list_1 = [[[1,a],[2,b]], [[3,c],[4,d]], [[1,a],[5,d]], [[8,r],[10,u]]]
```

I am trying to find whether an element is this list is similar to another element. Right now, I'm looping it twice i.e. for each element, check against the rest. My output is:

```
[[[1,a],[2,b]], [[1,a],[5,d]]]
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the first one [[1,a],[2,b]] and [[1,a],[5,d]] are similar because at least one element is common...i.e. [1,a] is the common one

Comment: The most efficient way to solve this would probably be to throw that data structure away and use something more reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) functions like this

```
from itertools import combinations
for item in combinations(list_1, 2):
    if any(i in item[1] for i in item[0]):
        print item
```

**Output**

```
([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']], [[1, 'a'], [5, 'd']])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that, by similar, you mean that the element has at least one matching pair within it. In this case, rather than do a nested loop, you could map each element into a dict of lists twice (once for each [number,str] pair within it). When you finish, each key in the dict will map to the list of elements which contain that key (i.e., are similar).

Example code:

```
list_1 = [[[1,'a'],[2,'b']], [[3,'c'],[4,'d']], [[1,'a'],[5,'d']], [[8,'r'],[10,'u']]]

d = {}

for elt in list_1:
    s0 = '%d%s' % (elt[0][0], elt[0][1])
    if s0 in d:
        d[s0].append(elt)
    else:
        d[s0] = [elt]

    s1 = '%d%s' % (elt[1][0], elt[1][1])
    if s1 in d:
        d[s1].append(elt)
    else:
        d[s1] = [elt]

for key in d.keys():
    print key, ':', d[key]
```

Example output:

```
1a : [[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']], [[1, 'a'], [5, 'd']]]
8r : [[[8, 'r'], [10, 'u']]]
2b : [[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]]
3c : [[[3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]]
5d : [[[1, 'a'], [5, 'd']]]
4d : [[[3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]]
10u : [[[8, 'r'], [10, 'u']]]
```

Any of the dict entries with length > 1 have similar elements. This will reduce the runtime complexity of your code to O(n), assuming you have a way to obtain a string representation of a, b, c, etc.